# Unable to print inner XML values using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, web-services, innerxml

I am trying to retrieve data from a SOAP web service using PowerShell. I am having issues retrieving values from the inner XML. The code is listed below.

In the `[XML]$body2` variable if I pass the `$queryid` variable then the values in the `else` condition of the `Response` function does not print. I debugged the code and `$queryid` is getting the correct value. If I remove `$queryid` and replace it with a number then the values print fine.

**Edit:** The `$queryid` should be set to a number which I then want to use in `$body2`.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$id1 = "1"
$id2 = "2"
$global:queryid = ""
$array = @()

function Main() {
    $uri = "https://mywebsite/CatalogTasks.asmx?WSDL"
    [XML]$body = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<soap:Body>
<Request xmlns="http://mywebsite.com">
    <user>user_id</user>
    <pwd>password</pwd>
    <fields>[Number],Tech name],[Description],[State]</fields>
    <condition>[State]='Open'</condition>
    <orderBy>[Number]</orderBy>
</Request>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"@
    Response $uri $body $id1
    Write-Host "Id: $global:queryid"
    $queryid = $global:queryid
    [XML]$body2 = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<soap:Body>
<RetrieveXML xmlns="http://mywebsite.com">
    <user>user_id</user>
    <pwd>password</pwd>
    <queryId>$queryid</queryId>
</RetrieveXML>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"@
    Response $uri $body2 $id2
}

function Response ($url, $bodyy, $id) {
    $resp = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Body $bodyy -ContentType "text/xml" -Proxy "http://proxy" -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials -Method POST)
    if ($id -eq 1) {
        $soap = $resp.Content
        $xpathfilter = "//*[local-name()='QueryId']"
        $Element = Select-Xml -Content $soap -XPath $xpathfilter
        $global:queryid = $Element.Node.'#text'      
    } else {
        $soap2 = $resp.Content
        $filter = "//*[local-name()='Number']"
        $Element2 = Select-Xml -Content $soap2 -XPath $filter
        $number = $Element2.Node.'#text'
        [array]$array = ($number)
        foreach ($i in $array){
            Write-Host $i
        }
    }
}

Main
```

Comment: At least in the code you've posted `$queryid` isn't set until _after_ you've constructed `$body2` and queried it with `Select-Xml`. If it does get set elsewhere beforehand: what does `$queryid.GetType().Name` return?

Comment: @mklement0 I am passing the value of $Global:queryid variable into the $queryid. $Global:queryid gets set after I construct $body variable. When I did $queryid.GetType().Name I got the value 'String'.

Comment: Your code initializes `$Global:queryId` - and therefore later the function-local `$queryId` to the _empty string_ (`""`), but it sounds like you're expecting it to be a number, right? Please clarify by updating your question directly. As an aside: use of `$Global:` is best avoided and even just defining `$queryid = ...` in the script scope is enough for your `Main` function to see that variable without the need for a scope specifier.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes the $queryid is supposed to hold a number in it. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: Thanks for updating; however, your code still does not set `$queryid` to a number, so I'm not surprised that it doesn't work. Please try to whittle your code down to an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mklement0 When I debug the code I see the value in $queryid but it fails to print the Innerxml values in the Else part of Function Response. However if I do $queryid="4566486432" just before $body2 is constructed it prints the values just fine.

Comment: What does the second SOAP request return, i.e. what is the actual value of `$soap2` when `Response` is invoked for the second time?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers $soap2 variable has SOAP response however the element RetrieveXMLResult does not have any output values in it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers This is what I get:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><RetrieveXMLResponse xmlns="http://mywebsite.com"><RetrieveXMLResult><ArrayOfCatalog_Task xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" /></RetrieveXMLResult></RetrieveXMLResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: Do you see a node `<Number>` in that response? Because I don't.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No I don't see it. With the code that I listed above the nodes does not show up however if I set the value of $queryid=''46475835" instead of $queryid=$global:queryid then it works just fine.

Comment: Compare the XML when using a variable and when using a literal (you can display it via `$bodyy.Save([Console]::Out)`) and check for differences.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers There is no difference in the XML at all. I can see the User, PWD and QueryID details in the XML using both the scenarios. This is the weirdest thing I've ever come across :/

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers 

I think I know what the issue is with my script, there's something to do with running the "Invoke-WebRequest" twice in the script. I separated the functions
into two different scripts, in the first script I did a Invoke-WebRequest and
obtained the QueryID and saved it to a text file. In the second script, I retrieved the QueryID from the text file and ran the Invoke-WebRequest again and it produced the desired output.